# android studio's design editor not work with the constraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I followed the [codelabs-guide](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html#7)
and find something wrong with my android-studio. The work space should be like this [image: CORRECT]

but my IDE looks like ...
[image: wrong]

the left panel of the layout is wrong, and right panel is the same as the codelabs image. How can I improve this?

My environment is:

- android studio 2.2 beta1
- java 1.8
- OS X 10.11
- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha4
- com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-beta1

Comment: Can you update to constraint layout alpha 7 ?
and if that doesn't fix the issue, can you post your layout xml file?

Comment: @NicolasRoard , I found the reason is imageview want to make constraint to somthing's  id `constraintLayout3`, but I never set id to my constraintLayout. Then I set id ,and it works

Comment: Ah, good to know! what you can also do with the latest versions of constraint layout is set the constraint to "parent", so you don't have to set an id explicitly. The latest betas of Android Studio will do that for you in fact.

Answer (score 0):

I found my ImageView try to make a constraint to id `constraintLayout3`, but my root constraintLayout has no id.

SOLUTION:
set a id `constraintLayout3` to my root constraintLayout.